# Angular 8: Routerlink not working in header component outside router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

my header component is in coreModule. I already imported **RouterModule** in coreModule still my **[routerLink]="['/login']"** is not working in header component.

When i used same code in other component which is rendered inside router-outlet it is working fine.

Comment: Any error? How are you importing the RouterModule?

Comment: No Error. import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';  and imports: [
    RouterModule
  ],

Comment: So, it is working, but it doesn't navigate. I guess a route guard is preventing it

Comment: where is your `/login` route defined

Comment: @rash111 did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If its a shared module, Make sure you import the routermodule in the shared.module.ts